# Function call in Material UI (React.js) not getting called

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formsy-material-ui, react-material-ui-form-validator, react-material-ui-carousel

- Started with Material UI today Don't know why this Function
  handelSubmit() is not getting called. Nothing is getting printed on console function is not getting called. Don't know where I am doing
  Mistake, Thank you.
- I am calling that function from form-tag, Also tried calling from
  outside but it's not working though.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { Button, Container } from '@material-ui/core';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyle = makeStyles({
  field: { marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20, display: 'block' },
});

export default function Create() {
  const classes = useStyle();
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [phnNO, setPhnNo] = useState('');
  const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
  const [nameError, setnameError] = useState(false);
  const [phnNoError, setphnNOError] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setnameError(true);
    setphnNOError(true);

    if (name == '') {
      setnameError(true);
    }
    if (phnNO == '') {
      setphnNOError(true);
    }
    if (name && phnNO && address) {
      console.log(name, phnNO, address);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <TextField
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        className={classes.field}
        label="Your Name"
        variant="outlined"
        color="secondary"
        fullWidth
        required
        error={nameError}
      />
      <TextField
        onChange={(e) => setPhnNo(e.target.value)}
        className={classes.field}
        label="Your mobile number"
        variant="outlined"
        color="secondary"
        fullWidth
        required
        error={phnNoError}
      />
      <TextField
        onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
        className={classes.field}
        label="Your address"
        multiline
        rows={4}
        variant="outlined"
        color="secondary"
        fullWidth
      />
      <Button
        className={classes.buttn}
        variant="outlined"
        color="primary"
        align="left">
        Register
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the type of the button as `submit` to make an actual form submission using the button.

```
      <Button
        className={classes.buttn}
        type="submit"
        variant="outlined"
        color="primary"
        align="left"
      >
        Register
      </Button>
```